# Why must a variable be declared outside of the scope of an if statement in order to exist?

Tags: c#

Why must a variable be declared outside the scope of an if statement in order to exist?

For example, the following code does not compile:

```
DateTime? myDate;
if (myDate != null)
{
    DateTime runDate = DateTime.Now;
}
else
{
    DateTime runDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
}

string foo = runDate.toString();
```

I understand the problem is that I need to declare `runDate` before the if statement, but why? If the compiler did allow this bit of code to work, would it really be any different than declaring it before? Or maybe better phrased, why did the devs who worked on the language/framework decide to do it this way?

Comment: hm, well a conditional declaration could lead to confusion. if this were in a loop, are you defining the same variable in each section o f the if?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, consider this, derived from your example:

```
DateTime? myDate;
if (myDate != null)
{
    String runDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
else
{
    DateTime runDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
}

string foo = runDate.ToString();
```

Following your proposal, the type of `runDate` (when `foo` is assigned) is unknown at compile-time, it could either be a `string` or a `DateTime`. This is not allowed in a statically-typed language.

Comment: @Dai This could be easily remedied through a technique called hoisting. I am more inclined to believe it's simply by design rather than by limitation.

Answer (score 4):

Variables don't exist outside the scope it's declared in.

In your case, the variable runDate is created inside your if statement, therefore it cannot be used outside.

This would be allowed

```
DateTime? myDate;
DateTime runDate;
if (myDate != null)
{
     runDate = DateTime.Now;
}
else
{
    runDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
}

string foo = runDate.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have the following:

```
if (something)
{
    string foo = "Abc";
}
else if (somethingelse)
{
    DateTime foo = DateTime.Now;
}
else
{
    //Do nothing
}
Some.Method(foo); //What type is foo, string or DateTime? Does it even exist?
```

As you can see, if you allow variables declared within the scope of if/else blocks to be used outside of these blocks, there's the potential that these declarations will conflict with each other (or even be missing in some "if branches"). Therefore, the designers of the language decided to disallow this. (Also, in general, a variable in C# declared within a block is only available within that block. Changing this for if statements only would be strange and inconsistent.) You can still declare variables inside if blocks, you just can't use these variables outside.

Answer (score 0):

even though `DateTime runDate` is declared in both sides of the `if` the compiler is not to know that unless deep analysis is ran to make sure which the compiler is not there to do. Also, declaring within the `if` is declaring out of scope for the method as you are declaring within the scope of the `if`, if you want to use something within the method, you need to declare it within the method's scope, and use it within the `if`.

```
DateTime? myDate ;
DateTime runDate ;

if (myDate != null)
{
    runDate = DateTime.Now;
}
else
{
    runDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
}

string foo = runDate.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because variables in C# are only valid within their blocks. There is nothing wrong with attempting to create the runDate variable within an if statement. What fails, is attempting to use the runDate variable outside of its block.

Declaration must be on the outer most block that it is used on. You could of course move the runDate.ToString() inside of the if statements and it would compile, if you so chose.

Answer (score 0):

Because of block scoping. It's just a lot easier for the compiler to work out, and also it's more logical. Each block (set of open and close brackets) has its local variables, that are only in scope inside that, and any sub-blocks. This makes sense and stops people going insane.